# Triggerhandler class and trigger issue - showing nullpoint exception error

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

```salesforce
trigger AssignedResourceTrigger on AssignedResource (after insert,after update){
    
    if(trigger.isAfter & AssignedResourceTriggerHandler.isRecursive){
        if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
            AssignedResourceTriggerHandler.assignedResourceOnServiceAppointment(trigger.new);
            AssignedResourceTriggerHandler.isRecursive = false;
        }
    }

}
```

This is the error:

AssignedResourceTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.AssignedResourceTriggerHandler: line 9, column 1 Trigger.AssignedResourceTrigger: line 3, column 1

Comment: Can you post the code from the trigger handler? The null exception is happening on line 9 in that class.

Comment: Please add necessary details to your question. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask